# HTML/CSS textarea - how to prevent word-wrap only for words with hyphen

Tags: html, css, word-break

In textarea I want use word-wrap / break word but not on words with hyphen

Here is the code

```css
#wrap {
  width: 250px;
  position: relative;
  font-family: sans-serif;
  height: 80px;
}

#wrap .area {
  resize: none;
  outline: none;
  display: block;
  width: 100%;
  padding: 0;
  position: absolute;
  top: 0;
  font-family: sans-serif;
  font-size: 20px;
  text-align: center;
}

#wrap textarea.area {
  left: 0;
  height: 100%;border: 2px solid;
  background: transparent;
}
```

```html
<div id="wrap" style="height: 300px;">
<textarea name="test" class="area" style="font-family: Comic Sans MS;">Line1
Line2
Line3-ShouldBeStillLine3-StillLine3</textarea></div>
```

The word 'Line3-ShouldBeStillLine3-StillLine3' should not be wrapped. I know it will not fit into the width of 250px but it is ok in this case. I do not get it to work within textarea.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Add [`white-space: nowrap;`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/white-space) on to the `textarea` element. But yes, as you mentioned it does not fit.

Edit ~ added `wrap="off"` to HTML `textarea` element.

```css
#wrap {
  width: 250px;
  position: relative;
  font-family: sans-serif;
  height: 80px;
}

#wrap .area {
  resize: none;
  outline: none;
  display: block;
  width: 100%;
  padding: 0;
  position: absolute;
  top: 0;
  font-family: sans-serif;
  font-size: 20px;
  text-align: center;
}

#wrap textarea.area {
  left: 0;
  height: 100%;
  border: 2px solid;
  background: transparent;
}

textarea {
  /* white-space: nowrap; ~ is replaced by wrap="off" in HTML */
}
```

```html
<div id="wrap" style="height: 300px;">
  <textarea name="test" class="area" style="font-family: Comic Sans MS;" wrap="off">Line1
Line2
Line3-ShouldBeStillLine3-StillLine3</textarea></div>
```

Comment: Sorry, I probably didn't make myself clear. Line1 and Line2 should of course remain in a separate line. So the nowrap should only apply to words with a hyphen.

Comment: @sabrakadabra well normally I would say nest the text you want to stay one line in a `span`. However, the `span` element is incompatible with `textarea`. So that won't work. The only thing I can think off would be to use `wrap="off"` in the HTML.

Comment: Thanks for your help. I found out that white-space="pre" works for my purpose.